# How do I write masked circle in createjs?

Tags: javascript, canvas, createjs, easeljs

I'm new user of createjs. And I want to write masked circle like below. The circle is masked (or clipped?) by blue rectangle. I could do this if my canvas size is same as blue rectangle. But in my case, canvas area is wider than blue rectangle.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I just answered a similar question here: [Draw section of shape with EaselJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38454511/draw-section-of-shape-with-easeljs/38462636#38462636)

1. Mask using another shape
2. Cache using a set size to constrain the content

Here is a sample with the mask: http://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/3kdo9u26/ -- in this case I just set the rectangle as the mask to the circle. Since they are both in the same coordinate space, it works properly.

```
// Rectangle
var s = new createjs.Shape().set({y:20});
s.graphics.f("blue").dr(0,0,800,240);

// Circle
var c = new createjs.Shape().set({x:325,y:220});
c.graphics.f("green").dc(0,0,120);

// Set the mask shape to the rectangle
c.mask = s;
```

Cheers,

Comment: You're super cooool! I could what I want to do with setting mask shape!.