# Draw section of shape with EaselJS

Tags: javascript, graphics, draw, shapes, easeljs

I have been trying to find out if it is possible to draw only a section of a shape using EaselJS. For example, is it possible to create a Rounded Rectangle, but only draw the top two thirds of it? (Effectively not displaying the bottom third).

Thank you in advance for any advice you may have!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the end goal? Depending on what you want to do, there are a few ways to do it:

1. Mask it using another shape to crop it
2. Cache it to the size you want

http://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/f1zh3qwx/

```
// Create 2 shapes
var s = new createjs.Shape().set({x:10, y:10});
s.graphics.f("red").ss(4).s("blue").rr(0,0,100,100,10);
var s2 = s.clone().set({x:150});
stage.addChild(s, s2);

// 1. Mask
s.mask = new createjs.Shape(new createjs.Graphics().dr(8,8,50,50));

// 2. Cache
s2.cache(-2,-2,50,50);
```

You can also use [roundRectComplex](http://createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Graphics.html#method_drawRoundRectComplex) to draw different corners. http://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/f1zh3qwx/1/

Comment: The mask was exactly what I was looking for, not sure how I missed it in the first place, thank you!